# wkhtmltopdf is unable to save Google line charts as PDF

Tags: python, wkhtmltopdf, python-pdfkit

I have developed a web application which generates reports using google charts. By using wkhtmltopdf I tried to save the HTML page as pdf but the google charts were not getting saved in the pdf. Can anyone help me with this

This is the pdf conversion code:

```
import pdfkit

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=r"C:\ProgramFiles\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
pdfkit.from_url('http://localhost/Project/upload.php','my_testpdf.pdf',configuration=config)
```

Comment: Are you getting errors? Can you share your PDF conversion code?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors but the google charts content is not getting converted to PDF. I don't know why